Joints not appearing but only baseplate appearing in gazebo 11(ros2 humble)
I'm new to ros and was following Antonio Brandi's ROS 2 - Learn by Doing! Manipulators course step by step. Not from udemy but from searching around a free one online (Yes, I'm broke but please I'll buy the courses once I'll get a job)
I've been trying to fix the error for a week before asking here. I deleted the work space and redo the course but still get the same error.
I suspect it's because of the arduinobot_controller.yaml or the stl files. I'm not sure. Thank you very much.
ros@ros:~/arduinobot_ws$ . install/setup.bash
ros@ros:~/arduinobot_ws$ ros2 launch arduinobot_description gazebo.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ros/.ros/log/2024-12-16-13-21-48-974945-ros-105890
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [105894]
[INFO] [gzserver-2]: process started with pid [105896]
[INFO] [gzclient-3]: process started with pid [105898]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [105900]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734330109.713324335] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734330109.713436334] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_plate
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734330109.713445322] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment claw_support
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734330109.713449309] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forward_drive_arm
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734330109.713453387] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_left
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734330109.713456864] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_right
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734330109.713460702] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment horizontal_arm
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734330109.713464118] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1734330110.360436859] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1734330110.360880256] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1734330110.363414231] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1734330110.375189393] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1734330110.375534187] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1734330111.130125231] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1734330111.270605732] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [arduinobot]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 105900]
[INFO] [gzclient-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 105898]
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1734332767.239060620] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 105894]
[INFO] [gzserver-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 105896]
ros@ros:~/arduinobot_ws$ 


controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10 # Hz

    arm_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    # gripper_controller:
    #   type: forward_command_controller/ForwardCommandController

    gripper_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

arm_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3

    command_interfaces:
      - position

    state_interfaces:
      - position

    open_loop_control: true
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true

gripper_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint_4

    #interface_name: position
      
    command_interfaces:
      - position

    state_interfaces:
      - position

    open_loop_control: true
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true

controller.launch.py
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
from launch.conditions import UnlessCondition
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


def generate_launch_description():

    robot_description = ParameterValue(
        Command(
            [
                "xacro ",
                os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory("arduinobot_description"),
                    "urdf",
                    "arduinobot.urdf.xacro",
                ),
            ]
        ),
        value_type=str,
    )

    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description }]
    )

    # controller_manager = Node(
    #     package="controller_manager",
    #     executable="ros2_control_node",
    #     parameters=[
    #         {"robot_description": robot_description,
    #          "use_sim_time": is_sim},
    #         os.path.join(
    #             get_package_share_directory("arduinobot_controller"),
    #             "config",
    #             "arduinobot_controllers.yaml",
    #         ),
    #     ],
    #     condition=UnlessCondition(is_sim),
    # )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[
            "joint_state_broadcaster",
            "--controller-manager",
            "/controller_manager",
        ],
    )

    arm_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["arm_controller", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    gripper_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["gripper_controller", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )


    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            robot_state_publisher_node,
            joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            arm_controller_spawner,
            gripper_controller_spawner
        ]
    )

display.launch.py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue


def generate_launch_description():
    #arduinobot_description_dir = get_package_share_directory("arduinobot_description")

    model_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name="model", 
        default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("arduinobot_description"), "urdf", "arduinobot.urdf.xacro"),
        description="Absolute path to robot urdf file")

    robot_description = ParameterValue(Command(["xacro ", LaunchConfiguration("model")]))

    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description}]
    )

    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = Node(
        package="joint_state_publisher_gui",
        executable="joint_state_publisher_gui"
    )

    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="screen",
        arguments=["-d", os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("arduinobot_description"), "rviz", "display.rviz")],
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        model_arg,
        joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        rviz_node
    ])

gazebo.launch.py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, SetEnvironmentVariable, IncludeLaunchDescription, TimerAction
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource


def generate_launch_description():
    # Declare launch arguments
    model_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name="model", 
        default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("arduinobot_description"), "urdf", "arduinobot.urdf.xacro"),
        description="Absolute path to robot urdf file"
    )

    # Set environment variable for Gazebo model path
    env_var = SetEnvironmentVariable("GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH", os.path.join(
                                        get_package_share_directory("arduinobot_description"), "share"))

    # Robot description from xacro
    robot_description = Command(["xacro ",LaunchConfiguration("model")])

    # Node to publish the robot description
    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description}]
    )

    # Start Gazebo server
    start_gazebo_server = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("gazebo_ros"), "launch", "gzserver.launch.py"))
    )

    # Start Gazebo client (to display GUI)
    start_gazebo_client = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("gazebo_ros"), "launch", "gzclient.launch.py"))
    )

    # Spawn the robot in Gazebo
    spawn_robot = Node(
        package="gazebo_ros",
        executable="spawn_entity.py",
        arguments=["-entity", "arduinobot", "-topic", "robot_description"]
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        env_var,
        model_arg,
        robot_state_publisher,
        start_gazebo_server,
        start_gazebo_client,  # Ensure that the client is included
        spawn_robot
    ])


arduinobot_gazebo.xacro
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="arduinobot">

  <!-- ROS 2 Control -->
  <gazebo>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
        <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
        <robot_param_note>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_note>
        <parameters>$(find arduinobot_controller)/config/arduinobot_controllers.yaml</parameters>
      </plugin>
   </gazebo>


</robot>

arduinobot_ros2_control.xacro
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="arduinobot">

    <xacro:property name="PI" value="3.14159265359" />


    <ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">

        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>

        <joint name="joint_1">
            <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-${PI / 2}</param>
        <param name="max">${PI / 2}</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>

        <joint name="joint_2">
            <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-${PI / 2}</param>
        <param name="max">${PI / 2}</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>

        <joint name="joint_3">
            <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-${PI / 2}</param>
        <param name="max">${PI / 2}</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>

        <joint name="joint_4">
            <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-${PI / 2}</param>
            <param name="max">0.0</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>

        <joint name="joint_5">
            <param name="mimic">joint4</param>
            <param name="multiplier">-1</param>
            <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-${PI / 2}</param>
            <param name="max">0.0</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>

    </ros2_control>

</robot>

arduinobot.urdf.xacro
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="arduinobot">

    <xacro:include filename="$(find arduinobot_description)/urdf/arduinobot_gazebo.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="$(find arduinobot_description)/urdf/arduinobot_ros2_control.xacro" />
     
    <xacro:property name="PI" value="3.14159265359" />
    <xacro:property name="effort" value="30.0" />
    <xacro:property name="velocity" value="10.0" />

    <xacro:macro name="default_inertial" params="mass">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value="${mass}" />
            <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                     iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"
                     izz="1.0" />
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>

    <xacro:macro name="default_transmission" params="number"> 
         <transmission name="transmission_${number}">
        <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
        <actuator name="joint_${number}" role="actuator1"/>
            <joint name="joint_${number}" role="joint1">
                <mechanical_reduction>1.0</mechanical_reduction>
            </joint>
         </transmission>
    </xacro:macro>

    <link name="world"/>

    <link name="base_link">
        <xacro:default_inertial mass="1.0"/>
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.5 -0.5 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file:///home/ros/arduinobot_ws/src/arduinobot_description/meshes/basement.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <link name="base_plate">
        <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.1"/>
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.39 -0.39 -0.56"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file:///home/ros/arduinobot_ws/src/arduinobot_description/meshes/base_plate.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.39 -0.39 -0.56"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/base_plate.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <joint name="virtual_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world"/>
        <child link="base_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint> 

    <joint name="joint_1" type="revolute">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="base_plate"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.307"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit lower="-${PI / 2}" upper="${PI / 2}" 
               effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="forward_drive_arm">
        <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.1"/>
        <visual>
            <origin rpy=" 0 -${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}" xyz="0.19 0.06 -0.08"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/forward_drive_arm.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin rpy=" 0 -${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}" xyz="0.19 0.06 -0.08"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/forward_drive_arm.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>    

    <joint name ="joint_2" type="revolute">
        <parent link="base_plate"/>
        <child link = "forward_drive_arm"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.02 0 0.35"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="-${PI / 2}" upper="${PI / 2}"
                effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="horizontal_arm">
        <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.1"/>
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="${PI / 2} 0 ${PI / 2}" xyz="-0.03 -0.4 -0.06"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/horizontal_arm.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin rpy="${PI / 2} 0 ${PI / 2}" xyz="-0.03 -0.4 -0.06"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/horizontal_arm.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link> 

    <joint name ="joint_3" type="revolute">
        <parent link="forward_drive_arm"/>
        <child link = "horizontal_arm"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.8"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="-${PI / 2}" upper="${PI / 2}"
               effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint>   


    <link name="claw_support">
        <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.05"/>
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 ${PI / 2}" xyz="0 -0.05 -0.15"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/claw_support.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
                </geometry>

        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin rpy="0 0 ${PI / 2}" xyz="0 -0.05 -0.15"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/claw_support.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>  

    <joint name ="horizontal_arm_to_claw_support" type="fixed">
        <parent link="horizontal_arm"/>
        <child link = "claw_support"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0.82 0"/>
    </joint>  


    <link name="gripper_right">
        <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.01"/>
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 -${PI / 2}" xyz="-0.1 0.50 -0.1"/>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/right_finger.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${PI / 2}" xyz="-0.1 0.50 -0.1"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/right_finger.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link> 

    <link name="gripper_left">
         <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.01"/>
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 -${PI / 2}" xyz="-0.04 0.50 -0.1"/>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/left_finger.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>  
    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${PI / 2}" xyz="-0.04 0.50 -0.1"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://arduinobot_description/meshes/left_finger.STL" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>  

    <joint name ="joint_4" type="revolute">
        <parent link="claw_support"/>
        <child link = "gripper_right"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.04 0.13 -0.1"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit lower="-${PI / 2}" upper="0.0" 
           effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name ="joint_5" type="revolute">
        <parent link="claw_support"/>
        <child link = "gripper_left"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.22 0.13 -0.1"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit lower="0.0" upper="${PI / 2}" 
           effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
        <mimic joint="joint_4" multiplier="-1"/>
    </joint>   

    <xacro:default_transmission number="1"/>
    <xacro:default_transmission number="2"/>
    <xacro:default_transmission number="3"/>
    <xacro:default_transmission number="4"/>

</robot>



